# How to increase open files limit mysql in linux

Tags: server, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

i want to increase "open files limit mysql" to 2084. what are the commands to run through ssh?

Answer (score 3):

To see the current limit, type:

```
ulimit -a
```

To check the limit for a particular user (I guess you would be interested in `mysql` user), type:

```
su mysql ulimit -a
```

To increase/modify the limit, do:

```
vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and add:

```
mysql hard nofile 2084 
mysql soft nofile 2084
```

Do the same for `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`.

You can also temporary increase the open files limit for the user you're currently logged in with:

```
ulimit -Hn 2084
```

Comment: When systemd is running then OS will be overridden over application parameters inspite of that my.cnf variable couldn't be load for this you can invoke at startup.
locate your service file in my case. 
root@fpe:/apps/fct-core# vim /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service

Comment: When systemd is running then OS will be overridden over application parameters inspite of that my.cnf variable couldn't be load for this you can invoke at startup.
locate your service file in my case. 
root@fpe:/apps/fct-core# vim /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service .

add this to your service section 
LimitNOFILE=infinity

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the MySQL internal limit, it is defined in `my.cnf` file by the variable `open_files_limit = 2084`
(see [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit) for details).

Depending on your version, the file to edit should be either `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`